# Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'

Tags: wcf

I am getting "Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'" error while developing WCF with REST services.I am new to WCF.

Answer (score 9):

In your web.config you must replace "enableWebScript" by "webHttp"

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that you cannot have both. See  http://kaushikghosh12.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/a-known-error-in-wcf-restful-service.html for more information.